# Proof by induction: $n^2<4^n$ $n \in \mathbb N$

Tags: induction

i need to proof on induction this questions:

$n^2<4^n$ $n \in \mathbb N$

i start with the basic $n=1$

$1^2<4^1$

then put $n=k$

$k^2<4^k$

then if $p(k)=T$ so $p(k+1)=T$

$(k+1)^2<4^{k+1}$

$k^2+2k+1<4^k\cdot 4$

by the indcution $k^2 < 4^k$

$4^k+2k+1<4^k\cdot 4$

and then I dont know what to do or even my way is right

Comment: you can't assume $(k+1)^2<4^{k+1}$ this is what you are trying to prove...

Comment: please make use of MathJax for editing your questions/answers/comments

Answer (score 0):

we assume that $$4^k>k^2$$ and we want to prove that $$4^{k+1}>(k+1)^2$$ multiplying the first inequality by $4$ we get
$$4^{k+1}>4k^2$$ and now we have $$4k^2\geq (k+1)^2=k^2+2k+1$$ and this is true if $$3k^2-2k-1\geq 0$$ for $k\geq 1$

Answer (score 0):

Your redaction is not good.

Induction theorem says :

> Let $\wp(n)$ a property.
>
> **1.** There is $n_0\in \mathbb N$ s.t. $\wp(n_0)$ true.
>
> **2.** For all $n\geq n_0$, $\wp(n)$ true implies $\wp(n+1)$ true.
>
> Therefore, $\wp(n)$ true for all $n\geq n_0$.

So in your case, $n_0=0$ work. Now suppose your property is true for an unspecified $n\geq 1$. Let prove that $\wp(n+1)$ true (i.e. $(n+1)^2<4^{n+1}$).

$$(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1\underset{hyp.}{\leq} 4^n+2n+1.$$
You also have that $n\leq n^2<4^n$ where the last inequality is by your induction hypothesis, and thus $2n<2\cdot 4^n$, and finally, $1<4^n$. Therefore,
$$(n+1)^2<4^n(1+2+1)=4\cdot 4^{n}=4^{n+1}.$$
Therefore $\wp(n+1)$ is true, and thus, by the theorem, $$n^2<4^n,$$
for all $n\geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to show that $4^{k+1}>(k+1)^2$, assuming that $4^{k}>k^2$. In order to solve this take a slightly different approach:

$$
4^{k+1}=4\cdot4^k>4k^2=(2k)^2>(k+1)^2
$$

Note that the last step holds since $2k>k+1$ iff $k>1$, which you may assume in this example once you have checked the inequality for small values of $k$.